# Name of Journal-Like Setting Description Lines Under Chapter Section Headings

Tags: fiction, style, formatting

Some fiction titles put a small block of text listing relevant setting details like the scene's time, date, and location between chapters' section headings and bodies.  Heres an example:

> #### Chapter or Section Heading
>
> Time
> Date
> Location
>
> Body Text…

Does this block of text have a name, and, if so, what is it?  I haven't yet been successful in finding any reference material giving it one so far.

Comment: I think I know what you're referring to, but for the sake of others', could you include an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: @TommyMyron:  Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably call it a *dateline* if it's describing time/date/location. If it's a subheader or describing anything about the content, it's a *dek* (that's the correct spelling, from [journalism,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_style#Subhead) without the C).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I _knew_ that thing had to have a name of _some_ kind…